# How to simulate parallel processes that uses a combination of resources in Simpy?

Tags: resources, shared, simpy

I have a simulation with 2 processes, P1 and P2. There are 2 resources, R1 and R2.

P1 uses R1 for 20' and R2 for 10'
P2 uses R2 for 10'

I would like to achieve the following logic using SimPy and need some guidance:

```
If R2 is free:
   run P2
If R1 and R2 are free:
   run P1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What SimPy offers is `resource.request()`.
Here is a small example for the first case.

```
resource_free = yield my_resource.request()
if my_resource_request() in resource_free:
   TODO: P1.run()
```

What we are doing here is that we are requesting the resource. When the resource yields, it becomes free to use, and we take it into `resource_free`.

[request() docs](http://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/simpy.resources.html?highlight=resource#simpy.resources.resource.Request)

Answer (score 0):

You need to query what's going on with your resources.

Let's define your resources as:

```
R1 = simpy.Resource(env, capacity = 1)
R2 = simpy.Resource(env, capacity = 1)
```

You can ask questions about the availability of these resources like so:

```
# Number of users currently using the resources.
num_users_R1 = R1.count()
num_users_R2 = R2.count()
```

Now you know this you can use your if statements to tell the sim what processes to follow.

```
# if both are free do process 1
if num_users_R2 + num_users_R2 == 2: 
   process_1()

# otherwise do process 2
else: 
   process_2()
```

You can read more about resource commands in the official documentation: http://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/simpy.resources.html